# Show my App in the list of apps when the youtube share button is clicked in ios

Tags: ios, youtube, share

Is that possible using the following ?

```
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
 <string>Open All Files</string>
 <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
 <string>Owner</string>
 <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
 <string>Editor</string>
 <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
 <array>
 <string>public.content</string>
 <string>public.data</string>
 </array>
 </dict>
```

I know for photos its possible but how should I do it for youtube kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For video sharing you can use, "public.video (kUTTypeVideo)". For ex.,

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

You can find other document type identifiers here : [DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)